# Execute something onchange checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox, onchange

Can you say me what i did wrong?
When i make a function and make a onchange="function()" it works.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" value="bar" />


$('input[name=test]').change(function(){
if($('input[name=test]').is(':checked')){
        alert('Checked');
    } else {
        alert('Not checked');
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you include jQuery and wrap your code in document.ready ?

Comment: It works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Ugbdh/1/   Maybe the bug is somewhere else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works here so it should also work fine for you .

http://jsfiddle.net/Sz3BK/

Which jquery version are you using ?

Comment: @Edocsyl - So you did'nt put your code inside document.ready then ?